# Compessing while writing millions of records to a file

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am writing a large number of records, probably 2 million records in a text file(zip). I would like to do that in chunks. I would to stream the data out of the database, rather than load it in all at once. That way I can write the data straight back out without having too much of it loaded into memory at once.

I know how it streams by chunks, but I'm not sure how I should compress (zip) the file when a file is still generating.

Here is what I have tried so far

```
import math
from django.db.models import Q
from django.conf import settings
import uuid

    with open(filename, 'w+') as file:
        oparray = [[0 for x in range(521)] for y in range(477)]
        file.write(BCH_HEADER)
        for sp in range(1, 209):
            local_result = local_BCH.filter(stress_period=sp)
            nonlocal_result = nonlocal_BCH.filter(stress_period=sp)

            if all(i == 0 for i in local_result) and all(i == 0 for i in nonlocal_result) and one:
                continue

            for r in local_result:
                oparray[r.m_row][r.m_col] = r.recharge
            for r in nonlocal_result:
                oparray[r.m_row][r.m_col] = r.recharge

            if all(i == 0 for i in oparray) and one:
                continue

            file.write(BCH_SUBHEADER)
            for x in range(1, 477):
                for y in range(1, 520, 10):
                    file.write('   {:e}   {:e}   {:e}   {:e}   {:e}   {:e}   {:e}   {:e}   {:e}   {:e} \n'
                               .format(oparray[x][y], oparray[x][y + 1], oparray[x][y + 2], oparray[x][y + 3],
                                       oparray[x][y + 4], oparray[x][y + 5], oparray[x][y + 6], oparray[x][y + 7],
                                       oparray[x][y + 8], oparray[x][y + 9]))

            if not one:
                oparray = [[0 for x in range(521)] for y in range(477)]
                second_local_result = second_local_BCH.filter(stress_period=sp)
                second_nonlocal_result = second_nonlocal_BCH.filter(stress_perios=sp)

                if all(i == 0 for i in second_local_result) and all(i == 0 for i in second_nonlocal_result):
                    continue

                for r in second_local_result:
                    oparray[r.m_row][r.m_col] = r.recharge
                for r in second_nonlocal_result:
                    oparray[r.m_row][r.m_col] = r.recharge

                if all(i == 0 for i in oparray) and one:
                    continue

                file.write(BCH_SUBHEADER)
                for x in range(1, 477):
                    for y in range(1, 520, 10):
                        file.write('   {:e}   {:e}   {:e}   {:e}   {:e}   {:e}   {:e}   {:e}   {:e}   {:e} \n'
                                   .format(oparray[x][y], oparray[x][y + 1], oparray[x][y + 2], oparray[x][y + 3],
                                           oparray[x][y + 4], oparray[x][y + 5], oparray[x][y + 6], oparray[x][y + 7],
                                           oparray[x][y + 8], oparray[x][y + 9]))
            oparray = [[0 for x in range(521)] for y in range(477)]
            print('current position:', sp)
        return filename
```

Comment: Is this question for `mysql` or for `postgresql`? They're two different database systems, and you're probably not using both.

Comment: @jmelesky sorry by mistake I selected mysql its postgre

Comment: Could you tell us what's wrong with your code? (Except for the broken indentation...)

Comment: @Bakuriu How I should compress (zip) the file when a file is still generating.

Comment: @user580950 Take a look at [`zlib.compressobj`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/zlib.html#zlib.compressobj). Quote from the documentation: *Returns a compression object, to be used for compressing data streams that won’t fit into memory at once.*